# Servicebus CBS Authentication Expired

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

I have a process where I consume messages from a queue. I'm facing an issue where it seems that the authentication expires. This is generally a **long running process** and I need to be re-authenticated and prevent this error from happening. The error I'm getting is the following:

```
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/receive_handler.py", line 391, in fetch_next
    timeout=timeout_ms)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/client.py", line 1074, in receive_message_batch
    receiving = self.do_work()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/client.py", line 395, in do_work
    if not self.client_ready():
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/client.py", line 377, in client_ready
    if not self.auth_complete():
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/client.py", line 358, in auth_complete
    timeout, auth_in_progress = self._auth.handle_token()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uamqp/authentication/cbs_auth.py", line 134, in handle_token
    raise errors.TokenExpired("CBS Authentication Expired.")
uamqp.errors.TokenExpired: CBS Authentication Expired.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/proj/main.py", line 655, in <module>
    main()
  File "/proj/main.py", line 637, in main
    service_bus()
  File "/proj/main.py", line 505, in service_bus
    msgs = receiver.fetch_next()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/receive_handler.py", line 396, in fetch_next
    self._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/servicebus/base_handler.py", line 136, in _handle_exception
    raise error
azure.servicebus.common.errors.ServiceBusError: Handler failed: CBS Authentication Expired.
```

I'm using azure-servicebus==0.50.3. I have tried with to use the latest version but the error is still there. The code I'm using is the following:

```
client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn)
    receiver = client.get_receiver(idle_timeout=0, mode=ReceiveSettleMode.PeekLock, prefetch=0)
    while True:
        msgs = receiver.fetch_next()
        for msg in msgs:
            msg.complete()
```

How can I make the authentication not expire? Should I refresh some token?

Comment: A few questions that will help diagnose this.
1. Does your real code do any processing before completion?  (as opposed to the pseudocode just doing completion immediately?)
2.  When you say latest version, you tried 7.0.0?
  2b. Have you tried just iterating over the receiver?  (for msg in receiver)?  You would have to unset idle_timeout if you wanted to receive forever, but am curious if this changes anything.
3. Regardless of #2b, I'd be curious what logs you see if you provide `logging_enable=True` to the ServiceBusClient initialization, and enable the 'azure' and 'uamqp' python loggers

Comment: 1. The processing is done after the message completion 2. Yes I tried 7.0.0 with some changes in the code of course with no luck. I will add the logging_enabled then and see what logs I get. Regarding 2b I think I have tried it at some point still no luck there.

Comment: Hmm.  In that case the logging will definitely be most useful.  At the risk of pedanticism let me echo the need for both the addition of `logging_enable`, and making sure the loggers are outputting at the proper verbosity for both `azure` and `uamqp`.  Am glad to take a peek as to if that turns up anything. (see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/0c5b1408d876464e268258d13cab43b965a58bc9/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/tests/utilities.py#L27) for what that looks like in our test code)